# JavaScript: Associate arrays and mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, knockout.js

I have a data set of skill clusters: clusterName, skillSet. I also have some static skill lookup repo which contain all skill set prefix with its cluster heading. I need to extract the cluster heading and corresponding skill set for the cluster list chosen by the users. I have created one object. But that doesnot suits my situation. I just need array of the object I created.

```
var clusterNames = ['AX', 'BX', 'CX', 'DX']; //Sample cluster Names
var clusterLookup = ['AX:A', 'AX:B', 'AX:C', 'AX:D', 'BX:E', 'BX:F', 'BX:G', 'CX:H', 'CX:I', 'CX:J', 'CX:K', 'CX:L', 'DX:M', 'DX:N']; //Lookup 
//object skillClusterMap to store cluster and skills
var skillClusterMap = {
    'cluster': [],
    'skills':[]
};

var manyclusters = skillClusterMap([]); //array of skillClusterMap - I need something like this
var tempClusterName = ['AX', 'BX']; // observable array
for (var i = 0; i < tempClusterName.count; i++) {
    skillClusterMap.cluster.push(cluster[i]); // This is working fine
    manyclusters[1].cluster.push(tempClusterName[i]); // I need this to get work
            ko.utils.arrayFilter(clusterLookup, function (item) {
                var lstSkillclusters = item.desc.split(':');

                if (lstSkillclusters[0] === tempClusterName[i]) {
                    subClusterList.push(lstSkillclusters[1]);                            
                }
            });
            manyclusters[i].skills.push(subClusterList); // I need this to get work
}
skillClusterMap.skills.push(subClusterList); // This is working fine
```

final view of object skillClusterMap with single entry,

[image]

final view of object skillClusterMap with multiple entry,

[image]

It ended with array of clusters and array of skills. But I need array of set of cluster and skills,

```
manyclusters[0]->cluster: 'AX' , skills: 'AX:A', 'AX:B', 'AX:C', 'AX:D'
manyclusters[1]->cluster: 'BX' , skills: 'BX:E', 'BX:F', 'BX:G'
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll split this answer in to two parts:

1. How to convert from one or two arrays of data, to an array of objects that wrap these data
2. How to use knockout.js to efficiently select sub-sets of the created data

### 1. Converting the data

You should see this more as a plain javascript exercise and not worry about knockout too early.

Looking at the data, it seems like you can do without the names array, since they are already in the skills. We're going to `reduce` the array of skills, passing along an object that holds a key for each cluster, pointing to an array of the skills in this cluster.

```js
var clusterLookup = ['AX:A', 'AX:B', 'AX:C', 'AX:D', 'BX:E', 'BX:F', 'BX:G', 'CX:H', 'CX:I', 'CX:J', 'CX:K', 'CX:L', 'DX:M', 'DX:N']; //Lookup 

// Create the map, keys are cluster name, hold array of skills
var skillMap = clusterLookup.reduce(function(map, skill) {
  var key = skill.substring(0, 2); // Extract key
  map[key] = map[key] || [];      // Create array if first of key
  map[key].push(skill);
  return map;
}, {});

// Create the objects
var models = Object.keys(skillMap).map(function(key) {
  return {
    cluster: key,
    skills: skillMap[key]
  };
});

console.log(models);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

### 2. Using knockout to select skills by cluster

Now, if you want to dynamically create sub-sets of these clusters, based on user input, a `ko.computed` is the way to go. For example, you can have an observable array of cluster names, and use this array to select skills:

```js
function ViewModel(map) {
  this.selectedClusters = ko.observableArray([]); 
  
  this.allClusters = Object.keys(map);
  this.selectedSkills = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      // This is the same logic used in 1, but wrapped in a computed
      // We're taking an array of cluster names as input, creating 
      // a new array with cherry-picked skills from our previously 
      // created map
      return this.selectedClusters()
        .reduce(function(result, cluster) {
          // Create models dynamically
          return result.concat({
            cluster: cluster,
            skills: map[cluster]
          });
      }, []);
  }, this);
};


var clusterLookup = ['AX:A', 'AX:B', 'AX:C', 'AX:D', 'BX:E', 'BX:F', 'BX:G', 'CX:H', 'CX:I', 'CX:J', 'CX:K', 'CX:L', 'DX:M', 'DX:N']; //Lookup 

// Create the map, keys are cluster name, hold array of skills
var skillMap = clusterLookup.reduce(function(map, skill) {
  var key = skill.substring(0, 2); // Extract key
  map[key] = map[key] || [];      // Create array if first of key
  map[key].push(skill);
  return map;
}, {});

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(skillMap));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: allClusters">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selectedClusters">
      <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul data-bind="foreach: selectedSkills">
  <li>
    <strong data-bind="text: cluster"></strong>:
    <span data-bind="text: skills"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```